# CI not adding data into db but adding '0'

Tags: database, model-view-controller, model, continuous-integration, codeigniter-2

I have a model, controller & view but when I fill in the form it just adds data into the data base where all the values are null anyone help? I've tried everything and I cannot get it to work, I am having the same issue with the register part however that just will not add anything into the database, I have connected it to it within the config so I know its not that.

Controller

```
<?php class Job extends CI_Controller { 

public function details() 
 { 
 $this->load->model('JobModel'); 
 $data['msg']=$this->JobModel->getJob(); 
 $this->load->view("details",$data); 
 } 


public function addJobForm(){ 
$this->load->helper('form'); 
$data['title']="Add a New Job"; 
$this->load->view("new_job_form",$data); 
} 

public function NewJob(){ 
$this->load->helper('form'); 
$data['title']="Add a New Job"; 
//$this->load->view("new_job_form",$data); 

$JobTitle=$this->input->post('JobTitle'); 
$JobDescription=$this->input->post('JobDescription'); 
$Date=$this->input->post('Date'); 
$Pay=$this->input->post('Pay'); 
$this->load->model("newjob");


if($this->newjob->addJobForm($JobTitle, $JobDescription, $Date, $Pay)){ 
 $data['msg']="Success"; 
 }

 else{ 
 $data['msg']="Something went wrong"; 
 } 
 $this->load->view("new_job_form",$data); 
} 

}

?>
```

Model

```
    <?php

Class NewJob extends CI_Model
{

  function JobModel(){
    parent::Model();
    $this->load->helper('form');                
  }

  function AddJobForm(){
    $this->load->database();
    $data = array(
              'JobTitle'=>$this->input->post('JobTitle'),
              'JobDescription'=>$this->input->post('JobDescription'),
              'Date'=>$this->input->post('Date'),
              'Pay'=>$this->input->post('Pay'),
              );
    $this->db->insert('jobs',$data);
  }
}
?>
```

HTML Form

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML> 
<html> 
<head> 
 <title><?php echo $title;?></title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="../CSS/style.css">
 <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" /> 
</head> 
<body>
 <? php include('navigationbar.php')?>
 <div id="container">
 <form style="text-align: center;width: 600px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    background-color: #ffd105;
    padding: 5px;
    display: block;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;">
   <?php echo form_open('job/newjob'); ?>
   <label for="JobTitle">Job Title</label>
     <input type="text" size="20" id="JobTitle" name="JobTitle"/>
     <br/>
     <label for="JobDescription">Job Description:</label>
     <input type="text" size="20" id="JobDescription" name="JobDescription"/>
     <br/>
     <label for="Date">Date:</label>
     <input type="text" size="20" id="Date" name="Date"/>
     <br/>
     <label for="Pay">Pay:</label>
     <input type="text" size="20" id="Pay" name="Pay"/>
     <br/>
     <input type="submit" value="Add Job"/>
   </form>
 <a href="http://helios.hud.ac.uk/u1059010/assignment2/CI/index.php/home/home_view/">Home</a>
 </div>
</body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't pass any data from your controller to your model better autoload your model and dont forget the mvc ,your model to view to controller to model.

```
 <?php

    Class NewJob extends CI_Model
    {

      function JobModel(){
        parent::Model();
        $this->load->helper('form');                
      }

      function AddJobForm($JobTitle, $JobDescription, $Date, $Pay){

        $data = array(
                  'JobTitle'=>$JobTitle,
                  'JobDescription'=>$JobDescription,
                  'Date'=>$Date,
                  'Pay'=>$Pay
                  );
        $this->db->insert('jobs',$data);
      }
    }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

problems in your view file
 remove

```
<form style="text-align: center;width: 600px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
background-color: #ffd105;
padding: 5px;
display: block;
color: #fff;
text-decoration: none;">
```

and 
`</form>`

from your code
you have create form using html tag and again create form using codeigniter function.
you may get help from 
http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/form_helper.html